# "factor predictors must have at most 32 levels"

Tags: r

I keep getting this error "factor predictors must have at most 32 levels" when trying to develop a decision tree. My y-value (Depression) is a factor with only 2 levels: No and Yes.
How can I fix this? Thank you.

R-output, where Depression is the response, and SMH is my dataset.

```
Error in tree(Depression ~ ., SMH, subset = train) : 
  factor predictors must have at most 32 levels
```

Trying to fit decision tree to predict Depression from 6 other variables, and I keep getting the error that
"factor predictors must have at most 32 levels," even though Depression only has 2 levels, which are Yes and No. I didn't expect this to be a problem, so not sure what I can do to fix this.

Comment: Please provide an example of your data set using the output of `dput(SMH)` and the code used prior to this error so that we can reproduce it.

Comment: `Depression` is your dependent, not a predictor.